# MapReduce integration in grid computing environnement

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, grid-computing

I would like to know: is it is possible to integrate Apache Hadoop or MapReduceFramework on a grid computing environment?

Comment: If you can run Java, you can import Hadoop Mapreduce APIs... However, then job would typically run within YARN, not your grid computing system

Comment: indeed, this is the case where we want to install hadoop side by side another middleware designed for the grid such as GT. but here, integration means a possible invocation of YARN by a deployed service on the grid, moreover, use hadoop or YARN as a grid service.

Comment: It's not "Hadoop or YARN", though... YARN is the resource manager running the applications. The Hadoop FileSystem (HDFS) is where data is stored. You could also look into Apache Mesos or just Apache Spark standalone cluster for job scheduling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly it is possible, I have seen it in play.

IBM does it with its Spectrum Symphony grid middleware platform.

For details on the solution read here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZUMP_7.1.2/sym_kc/sym_kc_managing_mapreduce_framework.html

Comment: Thank you, it is very helpful